# webdriverio step functions skipped but allure report shows all steps

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io

I have a feature file where the multiple steps are skipped and causing the Scenario to fail. The same scenario working for other users. I pulled the same repo from git so no changes in config and steps and features.

In allure result all the steps are showing and step exactly where it failed, but in terminal the steps are skipped randomly and error steps are showing something else. I tried making change in config, cloning the repo again, `npm install`, cache clean.

Comment: Let's show your source code and unexpected result!